# Aloha editor IE8 error with Plugin Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, aloha-editor

I need help with one error I have with **Plugin Block**.

I have two editors with **Aloha**, I define in the first editor, one Block(span),and finally I want drag/drop this block to the second editor, I can do it but after I have this error in **IE8**:

> JScript: 'Console' is undefined

and the behaviour of the editor is strange.

I'm trying to find a solution for this in Google, but I've had no luck.

```
Aloha.jQuery('.variable').alohaBlock();
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to define the console function so it will not error out **because of the console not being available**. But because it's trying to write to the console, I'm assuming there may be an error which it's trying to tell you about.

Taken from [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/js/plugins.js). Just place this self executing function before you add `Aloha`(preferably before you add any javascript at all, this should be first).

```
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: @user3290821 if this worked for you please accept the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `console` object is not available in older browsers. This plugin probably uses either `console.log()` or `console.error()` somewhere in the code for debugging purposes.

You could make an empty implementation of those to make sure it doesn't break when in an older browser:

```
if (!console)
{
    console.log = function(){};
    console.error = function(){};
}
```